# pandas subtracting value in another column from previous row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe (named df) sorted by identifier, id_number and contract_year_month in order like this so far:

```
**identifier id_number contract_year_month collection_year_month**
   K001        1         2018-01-03           2018-01-09
   K001        1         2018-01-08           2018-01-10
   K001        2         2018-01-01           2018-01-05
   K001        2         2018-01-15           2018-01-18
   K002        4         2018-01-04           2018-01-07
   K002        4         2018-01-09           2018-01-15
```

and would like to add a column named 'date_difference' that is consisted of contract_year_month minus collection_year_month from previous row based on identifier and id_number (e.g. 2018-01-08 minus 2018-01-09),
so that the df would be:

```
**identifier id_number contract_year_month collection_year_month date_difference**
   K001        1         2018-01-03           2018-01-09            
   K001        1         2018-01-08           2018-01-10           -1
   K001        2         2018-01-01           2018-01-05
   K001        2         2018-01-15           2018-01-18           10
   K002        4         2018-01-04           2018-01-07
   K002        4         2018-01-09           2018-01-15            2
```

I already converted the type of contract_year_month and collection_year_month columns to datetime, and tried to work on with simple shift function or iloc but neither doesn't work.

```
df["date_difference"] = df.groupby(["identifier", "id_number"])["contract_year_month"]
```

Is there any way to use groupby to get the difference between the current row value and previous row value in another column, separated by two identifiers? (I've searched for an hour but couldn't find a hint...) I would sincerely appreciate if you guys give some advice.

Comment: Two questions: do you have only two dates per group? are you interested in the difference of last date in contract_year_month and earliest collection_year_month? If the answer to second one is yes, I will post and answer.

Comment: Nah I have multiple dates per group; that was just an example of my df, and I am interested in all differences between contract_year_month date and its corresponded previous collection_year_month date.

Comment: @Jay please consider accepting one of these answers.  You can show your appreciation by upvoting answers you find helpful and accepting the one you find most helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one potential way to do this.

First create a boolean mask, then use `numpy.where` and `Series.shift` to create the column date_difference:

```
mask = df.duplicated(['identifier', 'id_number'])

df['date_difference'] = (np.where(mask, (df['contract_year_month'] - 
                                         df['collection_year_month'].shift(1)).dt.days, np.nan))
```

[output]

```
    identifier  id_number   contract_year_month collection_year_month   date_difference
0   K001    1   2018-01-03  2018-01-09  NaN
1   K001    1   2018-01-08  2018-01-10  -1.0
2   K001    2   2018-01-01  2018-01-05  NaN
3   K001    2   2018-01-15  2018-01-18  10.0
4   K002    4   2018-01-04  2018-01-07  NaN
5   K002    4   2018-01-09  2018-01-15  2.0
```

Comment: @Jay Glad it helped!

Comment: This depends on being sorted.  If it wasn't sorted, the mask wouldn't work.  But of course, OP said it was already sorted so good answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach using your `grouby()` (*Updated* based on feedback from @piRSquared):

```
In []:
(df['collection_year_month']
 .groupby([df['identifier'], df['id_number']])
 .shift() - df['contract_year_month']).dt.days

Out[]:
0     NaN
1    -1.0
2     NaN
3    10.0
4     NaN
5     2.0
dtype: float64
```

You can just assign this to `df['date_difference']`

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate it.

Comment: You don't need the `apply`.  You can stick to `df['collection_year_month'].groupby('id_number').shift() - df['contract_year_month']`

Comment: @piRSquared excellent. You do need `df['id_number']` in the `groupby()`